# How to shrink content of pdf page according to media box dimensions in pdfbox 2.0

Tags: pdfbox

How to resize pdf page content to its media box size in apache pdfbox 2.0 ?
My application will receive pdf document as input with different margins.
If margin is with "x+1" inch , then content has to be fit into predefined media box dimensions 612 X 792

Comment: How is your question different to what was answered in the comments in your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292264/how-to-create-pagedrawer-instance-in-pdfbox-2-0 Or is your question about how to do the matrix calculations?

Comment: previous answer was fine. But my application draw other images on the right side. Previous solution resizes entire page as per my reduction factor. So my application draw other images at different place as intended. So now i want the content of page should be resized to media box dimensions (through out my application, these dimensions will not change for pdf document). Thanks for help.

Comment: I hope that my problem is understandable

Comment: No I don't understand. "So my application draw other images at different place as intended" Do you want to draw images additionally to resize a PDF?

Comment: No, these additional images are not part of pdf page content. these additional images are drawn out side of content, at location, as pre-configured. If the entire page is resized, these additional images are drawn differently as against pre-configured locations

Comment: Then draw them first, i.e. before you do the transform mentioned in the other issue.

Comment: hmm. I cannot draw them while pdf document preparation, they will be drawn by user (application functionality)

Comment: That doesn't change anything, the user must draw them in a content stream that is prepended to the existing content stream.