# how to change exist text position in pdf by itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

sorry,you may not understand my problems,because i am not good at english.
i want to add some labels at the top and bottom of pdf,but the label position can set minus.if i set a minus,i should make heigh larger to set label.
i got help from [How to resize existing pdf page size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375150/how-to-resize-existing-pdf-page-size)
to change my pdf pagesize.then i encountered another problem,when i set lly as a
minus, my text was truncated,then i want to add bottom length to top, but i do not know how to move the text up to make the text in center.

key codes

```
float newTop = rectangle.getTop();
                    if (printSet.getHeaderMargins() < 0) {
                        newTop += height2Offset(PrintSet.defaultMargins - printSet.getHeaderMargins());
                        headMargins = height2Offset(PrintSet.defaultMargins);
                    }
                    if (printSet.getFooterMargins() < 0) {
                        newTop += height2Offset(PrintSet.defaultMargins - printSet.getFooterMargins());
                        footMargins = height2Offset(PrintSet.defaultMargins);
                    }
                    float[] newBoxValues = new float[] {
                            rectangle.getLeft(),
                            rectangle.getBottom(),
                            rectangle.getRight(),
                            newTop
                    };
                    PdfArray newBox = new PdfArray(newBoxValues);
                    PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(page + 1);
                    pageDict.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, newBox);
                    pageDict.put(PdfName.MEDIABOX, newBox);
```

[image]

Comment: i spend much time drawing a beautiful picture to describe my quesiton!oh,so powerful

Comment: *"then i encountered another problem,when i set lly as a
minus, my text was truncated"* - Thus, this is your actual problem and should be the focus of your question because *"to add bottom length to top"* and *"to move the text up to make the text in center"* is an unnecessarily complicated way to solve that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are defining a new page size like this:

```
float[] newBoxValues = new float[] {
    rectangle.getLeft(),
    rectangle.getBottom(),
    rectangle.getRight(),
    newTop
};
```

This creates a bigger rectangle, but that rectangle only expands the page towards the top.

I think you should create the new rectangle like this:

```
float[] newBoxValues = new float[] {
    rectangle.getLeft(),
    rectangle.getBottom() - extramarginBottom,
    rectangle.getRight(),
    rectangle.getTop() + extramarginTop
};
```

I can't help you define the value of `extramarginBottom` and `extramarginTop` because I'm not sure what your `height2Offset()` method is supposed to do, nor what `PrintSet.defaultMargins`, `printSet.getHeaderMargins()`, and `printSet.getFooterMargins()` are about.

Basically, `extramarginTop` is the height to be added at the top, whereas `extramarginBottom` is the height to be added at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: I have resolved the question by your method.don't care about the height2Offset() method,it just change the page real length to pixels，like the A4 page real length  210mm×297mm  to 841×594.thanks for you answer.