# Resize Pages with lowagie.itext from PdfImportedPage

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have this code for copy a pdf. How can resize the pages to A4?

Currently you can come within the pdf pages with different size, I want all the same size

```
private void getPdfPages(byte[] pdf1, PdfCopy copy) throws IOException, BadPdfFormatException {
    PdfReader reader;
    int n;
    reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdf1));
    try {
        Field f = reader.getClass().getDeclaredField("encrypted");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(reader, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int page = 0; page < n;) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: How do you want to resize? Do you expect similarly sized inputs and only want to move the page borders a bit without changing the contents? (This is easy.) Or do you want to scale everything including annotations and adapt link destination targets? (This is difficult.) Or do you want to scale the static contents and drop annotations and destinations? (Easy again.)

Comment: Some pages come in letter size and I want to put them all in A4 format

Comment: So you *only want to move the page borders a bit without changing the contents? (This is easy.)*

Comment: yes! without changing the content

Comment: In that case you can use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21378162/1729265), you merely have to change the `width` and `height` values to those of A4 pages, `width = 595` and `height = 842`.